# iOS UI connection to the code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Every I run this code it gives `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding.'`
All Im doing is connecting `button` to the `label`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lable: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        lable.text="done"
    }

}
```

The error will be refered to `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`

Comment: "All Im doing is connecting button to the label". What do you exactly mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your storyboard, select your ViewController and go to this section

[image]

Check that you don't any invalid Outlet here. It happens that if you connect an outlet and then you change the name of the variable by code, xcode'll still trying to find the previous one and will crash.